# how to retreive from memory an object associated to a destroyed object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

My application has a Micropost model and a Comment model.
I introduced in the Micropost partial links for showing/hiding and refreshing comments:

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
  <span class="user"><%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %></span>
  <span class="content">
    <%= micropost.content %>
    <%= image_tag micropost.picture.url if micropost.picture? %>
  </span>
  <% if micropost.comments.any? %>
    ~ <%= link_to "Show/hide comments", "#", class: "comments-link", remote: true %>
    ~ <%= link_to "Refresh comments", fetch_comments_path(micropost), remote: true %>
  <% end %>
  <% if logged_in? && (current_user == micropost.user || current_user.friend?(micropost.user)) %>
    <div class="comment-section">
        <%= form_for(current_user.comments.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
            ...
        <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="comments-section">
    <% if micropost.comments.any? %>
        <ol id="comments_micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
            <% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
                <%= render comment %>
            <% end %>
        </ol>
    <% end %>
  </div>    
</li>
```

This links are added to the page after creating the first comment and are loaded if the micropost has comments. 
However, in case there is just one comment and it is deleted, they are useless so I would like to remove them with Ajax via the destroy action of the comments controller. 
I am having my troubles to realize this. 
The main problem is that I cannot refer to the micropost using the to-be-destroyed comment.
Once the comment is destroyed any `@micropost = @comment.micropost` association would return a nil object:

```
def destroy
  @comment = current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @micropost = @comment.micropost
  @comment.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      flash[:success] = "Comment deleted"
      redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
    end
    format.js
  end
end
```

Thus, inside `create.js.erb` I cannot use a `if @micropost.comments.nil? remove links` conditional

Moving `@comment.destroy` after the `respond_to` block would not work for `format.html`, without refreshing the page.
If it worked, I could use a if `@micropost.comments.count == 1 remove links` conditional in `create.js.erb`

I cannot move `@comment.destroy` inside the `format.html` block, because it would not be used by `format.js`.
What solution can I use?

The delete link in the comment partial is:

```
<%= link_to "delete", comment, method: :delete, remote: true %>
```

Is it possible to pass in `link_to` a params value equal to `micropost.id`, such as:

```
<%= link_to "delete", comment, method: :delete, micropost_id: micropost.id, remote: true %>
```

so that I can write in the destroy action: 
 
`@micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you destroy your object it is destroyed form database and all reference keys are destroyed immediately. So you can first grab post Id and the remove comment.

```
def destroy
 @micropost_id = @comment.micropost.id
 @comment.destroy
end
```

Now you can use `@micropost_id` to take another action or to redirect to the parent post like this:

```
redirect_to '/microposts/'+ @micropost_id
```

Or

```
redirect_to MicroPost.find(micropost_id)
```

Comment: `@micropost_id` as defined above would not be retrievable after destroying `@comment`, because is defined as `@comment.micropost.id` which is nil.

Comment: @micropost_id remains until your ajax call session remains. You can use it in create.js.erb. Once you refresh page then you cannot use it. You can explain your problem in few words. What you want to acheive ?

Comment: I would like to use a `<% unless Micropost.find(@micropost_id).comments.any? %>` remove links in create.js.erb

Comment: You have no comments associated with microspost then what above statement returns. Any errors or boolean value.